# Year to date vs Year to date last year | Google Sheets

Tags: date, google-sheets

I would like to calculate the Year to date (YTD) value for this year and compare it to the same period last year in Google Sheets. 
I am setting up a live dashboard that compares sales this year to last year, and I want it to be live to the hour (year over year).

I want two separate results: units and volume for right now (year to date unit sales this year versus year to date unit sales through the same date last year plus year to date sales volume this year versus year to date sales volume through the same date last year)

My data looks like this:

```
1/2/2017    3045 Corrib Drive   $173,000.00
1/5/2017    15 Meadowlarke Drive    $154,900.00
1/7/2017    2611 Tupelo Terrace $126,000.00
1/7/2017    7000 Atascadero Lane    $249,900.00
1/8/2017    2003 Sara Lee Lane  $295,000.00
1/9/2017    329 Gould Road  $345,000.00
1/9/2017    1088 Landings Loop  $187,000.00
1/9/2017    4052 Brandon Hill Drive $295,000.00
1/9/2017    2008 Scenic Drive   $105,000.00
1/10/2017   2425 Limerick Drive $280,000.00
1/11/2017   8697 Alexandrite Court  $235,000.00
1/11/2017   4620 Whitetail Pass $435,000.00
1/11/2017   3069 N. Fulmer Circle   $130,000.00
1/11/2017   Lot A32 Rivers Landing  $205,265.00
1/12/2017   911 Lasswade Drive  $280,000.00
1/13/2017   8819 Minnow Creek   $198,000.00
1/14/2017   1813 Bitter Root Trail  $261,500.00
1/14/2017   1037 Piney Z Plantation Rd  $186,000.00
1/14/2017   1037 Piney Z Plantation Rd  $186,000.00
1/16/2017   1365 E. Windwood Way    $247,500.00
1/16/2017   1106 Linwood Drive  $125,900.00
1/20/2017   Lot 29, Blk L, Delores Madison  $191,000.00
1/21/2017   2822 Morningside Drive  $170,000.00
1/21/2017   2822 Morningside Drive  $170,000.00
1/26/2017   2425 Limerick Drive $275,000.00
1/28/2017   4537 Louvinia Court $188,830.00
1/28/2017   1039 Winter Lane    $190,000.00
1/28/2017   2023 Taylor Road    $170,000.00
1/28/2017   2832 Royal Isle Drive   $495,000.00
1/29/2017   2916 Royal Isle Drive   $425,000.00
1/30/2017   5663 Tecumseh Drive $281,750.00
1/30/2017   2007 Chimney Swift Hollow   $476,400.00
1/30/2017   5042 Sundance Lane  $258,000.00
1/31/2017   806 Lothian Drive   $272,000.00
1/31/2017   806 Lothian Drive   $272,000.00
```

Comment: and explain it more properly (with examples) what you are after

Comment: Welcome. +1 for @player0 comments. Where is the rest of your data? if this is it, then `sum` and `count` look as though they would do the trick.

Comment: Correction: `countifs` and `sumifs`. I think they'll work for you.

Comment: I have shared a copy of the data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Opqeh5dL2yvw0pMY3L-IxZ9Afihs_eC9WmCkQl42uRA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Each day, I want to compare year-to-date (count of sales) today (January 1, 2019 through March 15, 2019) with the count of sales through the same days last year (January 1, 2018 through March 15, 2018). Tomorrow, I want the report to be through March 16 of each year etc.   

In the same manner, I want to compare year-to-date sales volume (sum of sales price).

Here is the test file and thank you!: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Opqeh5dL2yvw0pMY3L-IxZ9Afihs_eC9WmCkQl42uRA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I was tempted to simply repeat my comment that `countifs` and `sumifs` were the answer to your problem. To be fair to you, I did have to do some googling to figure out how to write the formulas to cover entire columns of data (which could be expected to grow), and so I created the attached answer. But I think this should have been within your grasp too. As I noted in the answer, the only "less-obvious" element is how to calculate the running YTD date. In the future please heed the suggestions of @Cooper: share your data at the outset and ensure your explanation is crystal clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was given to you: use sumifs and countifs.

The only less-obvious element of this worksheet was extracting the current day and month from the date (`=now()`)using `month` and `day`. This allows to to calculate the ytd date for each of the relevant years.

Here is a worked example showing the formula for row 4. Note the absolute references. This enables you to simply 
copy the formula down to the 5 subsequent rows (2016,,2017, 2017, 2018, 2019)

---

[image: Worked example]

For future reference, may I respectfully suggest that creating a sheet such as this where you expect to display the data, and the columns and rows where you expect the data to appear, is part of the process of creating your question by displaying how you would expect your data to appear.

Comment: Tedinoz, this is perfect! Thank you so much. In the future, I will frame my question with a sheet as you suggested.